# How to run java program with multiple jars and multiple classes with cmd or terminal?

Tags: java, cmd, javac

This is what I have tried so far to compile

```
javac -d bin -cp "lib/*" src/*.java
```

This seems to compile everything correctly, the problem is when I try running. 
This what I tried

```
cd bin
java -cp "lib/*" App <arguments>
java -cp "../lib/*" App <arguments>
```

or from root directory

```
java -cp "lib/*" bin/App
```

I have tried multiple suggestions that I found online but none of them work.
The error that I always get is

```
ClassNotFoundException
```

can someone please help me run this?

Comment: Make sure your paths exist. It seems like you are trying to access the "lib" directory from within the "bin" directory in the second code snippet, but not the first.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the bin directory in your classpath.

If you are inside the bin directory then you can use ".":

```
java -cp ".:../lib/*" App <arguments>
```

In Linux/Unix the classpath separator is ":", but in Windows it is ";".

Or if you are in the parent directory (where bin and lib directories are):

```
java -cp "bin:lib/*" App <arguments>
```

Comment: The second command works, the app runs. However, the lib folder contains Derby Embedded jars. When I try to log in in the app, I get the "No suitable driver found error". I know that error is because the app is not "seen" those jars in the lib folder.

Comment: Okay fixed it. The problem was that bin was being loaded before lib which contains all jars necessary to run the app. By switch from java -cp "bin:lib/*" App <arguments> to java -cp "lib/*:bin" App <arguments> worked. Thank you

Comment: The order shouldn't matter if your bin directory only has your own classes (which seems to be the case).